# Is it possible to add two secp256k1 points to get a "shared key"?

Tags: private-key, public-key, ecdsa, secp256k1, shared

As I know from the Elliptic Curve Diffie Hellman (ECDH), you can create a "Shared Key": https://asecuritysite.com/encryption/ecdh2

This will look like this:

```
dA × dB × G = Shared Key

QB = dB × G

QA = dA × G
```

But is it possible to get the sum of dA and dB? (Plusing the value of each private key?)

```
dA + dB × G = ???
```

How to get a "Shared Key" when adding each private key (plus)?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, `QA + QB = (dA + dB) × G`, but this isn't used in ECDH as QA + QB can be calculated by third parties.

You can read about this property [here](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/a/53980/).

Comment: `QA + QB` can not be calculated by third parties? That is, the point G does not allow this to be done. Or how can `QA + QB` be calculated? Maybe in a different way?

Comment: If you know the points QA and QB, what you should do is draw the curve, mark the points QA and QB, connect them with a line, find where the line intersects the curve (apart from QA and QB). The third intersection will be -(QA + QB). You can then reflect the point over the X axis to find the point QA + QB. You can read more about addition [here](https://fangpenlin.com/posts/2019/10/07/elliptic-curve-cryptography-explained/). (note that there are also some modulo operations) @IziTors

Comment: How on the graph of the curve can they get the sum of the total private keys (dA + dB) by calculating QA + QB?

Comment: It’s assumed to be impossible to find dA + dB from QA + QB, but you can find (dA + dB) x G if you know QA and QB by adding them. If you know QA and QB or QA + QB you can’t find dA or dB or their sum.

Comment: And there are minus points QA - QB, and accordingly minus (dA - dB) x G ?

Comment: @IziTors Yes. it's correct.

Comment: Replacing `y2` with `-y2` [is all you need to do](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/a/11336). @IziTors